# How to read a matrix from a file so that you can perform operations on it?

Tags: java, matrix

This is an example of input.txt:
[image]

I need to read the matrix from the input.txt file and output it to the output.txt file in the same format. The matrix can be stepped (not rectangular). The size of the array is determined as it will be entered by the user in input.txt. The input format should be shown in the screenshot.

I tried to read the matrix using rows, I can read a rectangular matrix and if we know its size in advance.

```
 void readMtx() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));

    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    while (br.ready()) {
        lines.add(br.readLine());
    }
    int matrixWidth = lines.get(0).split(" ").length;
    int matrixHeight = lines.size();

    Double[][] matrix = new Double[matrixHeight][matrixWidth];

    for (int i = 0; i < matrixHeight; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixWidth; j++) {
            String[] line = lines.get(i).split(" ");
            matrix[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(line[j]);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < matrixHeight; i++) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matrix[i]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define a multi-dimensional array without an initialiser, you're only required to specify its first dimension. A multi-dimensional array doesn't **have to be** rectangular:

```java
void readMtx() {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));

    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    while (br.ready()) {
        lines.add(br.readLine());
    }
    int matrixHeight = lines.size();

    Double[][] matrix = new Double[matrixHeight][];

    for(int i = 0; i < matrixHeight; ++i) {
        String[] nums = lines.get(i).split("\s*,\s*");
        matrix[i] = new Double[nums.length];
        for(int j = 0; j < nums.length; ++j) {
            matrix[i][j] = Double.valueOf(nums[j]);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < matrixHeight; ++i) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matrix[i]));
    }
}
```

My `input.txt` looks like this:

```
1
2, 3
4, 5, 6
```

And the function above prints:

```
[1.0]
[2.0, 3.0]
[4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

- Double is a wrapper Class, not the primitive floating point type.
- Files and Path (generalisation of File) are very useful.
- Stream is very expressive for conversions.

So:

```
void readMtx() throws IOException {
    double[][] matrix =
        Files.lines(Paths.get("input.txt"))  // Stream<String> of lines
        .map(line -> line.split(",\\s*))     // Stream<String[]> of line words
        .map(words -> Arrays.stream(words)
                 .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
                 .toArray())                 // Stream<double[]>
        .toArray();                          // double[][]
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matrix[i]));
    }
}
```